# can't access wamp projects online

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, ip, wamp

A lot of similar questions to mine,, but really none addresses my issue!

I installed Wamp on a pc (win 7) connected to internet and i gave it a real IP (78.10*.*.*) in which i can access it anywhere.

i did the following:

- changes in httpd & phpmyadmin,, (deny all replaced with allow all) (server name "localhost:80" replaced with my public ip 78.10*.*.*:80) ( denied replaced with granted) (added ::1)
- changes in phpsysinfo, sqlbuddy,webgrin (requier local host removed ,, deny from all replaced with allow from all)
  -put wamp online from its icon
  -firewall is turned off
  -full permission granted on local hard C and put on shared too

when i request 78.10*.*.* on another computer (not in my LAN) the wamp index previewed and i can access Tools(phpinfo, phpmyadminn) & Your Aliases(phpmyadmin, phpsysinfo, sqlbuddy, webgrin) but i can't access my project which located in the www directory
when i press on project named "m" a redirect page previewed and redirected me to page named localhost and says page not available, if i did same thing on my server the redirected page redirect me to localhost and i can access my project

any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advice

Comment: What is inside the project folder `m`. Is there a htaccess file or something? Put an index.php file inside the `m` folder with the following code: `<?php die(phpinfo());` and show us the output

Comment: thanks Fleuv for your reply,
for sure there an index.php file onside the folder m

Comment: Seems to be a "Moodle" issue.

Comment: yes Stewiezzz a moodle package files inside the folder m
but how to fix it, any idea?

Comment: by the way, moodle is working normally on my server as locally

Comment: Hmm indeed Stewiezzz you're right. I experienced this issue before and was able to fix it, unfortunately I do not remember exactly how I fixed it. I guess it was something with the cache but i'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `(wwwroot='localhost')` to `78.10*.***.***` in your "Config.php" inside your Moodle folder.

To make your moodle folder your root directory, do the following:

You will have to edit two things inside of the httpd.conf file /wamp/apache2/conf/httd.conf find:

```
DocumentRoot "/wamp/www"
```

change to

```
DocumentRoot "your_moodle_folder"
```

then find:

```
<Directory "wamp/www">
```

change to

```
<Directory "your_moodle_folder">
```

Save it and restart apache.

Comment: can i move files inside folder m to www directory and access moodle directly from ip ( i'll delete wamp index)

Comment: i just added "m" after C:/wamp/www in both documentroot and director,,, and it worked 
Again Thanks Stewiezzz, you are the best :)

Comment: No problem haha, just edit your post to change the last few digits of your IP for privacy reasons, I'll do the same to my post.

Comment: Done, if my server faced an attack in the following days then it should be you ;) lol

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not into the whole Ddos attacks haha